# onBlur and onSubmit interference

Tags: javascript, forms, post, scroll

Here is my complete script... You can just create test.php and throw it in.

It looks like this:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo '' . $site_url . '' ?>includes/libary.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function saveScrollPositions(theForm) {
if(theForm) {
var scrolly = typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var scrollx = typeof window.pageXOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
theForm.scrollx.value = scrollx;
theForm.scrolly.value = scrolly;
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="padding: 200px 0 200px 0;">

<?php
    $notes = $_POST['internal_notes'];
    $bonid = $_POST['reciept_id'];

    echo '<form name="notes" method="post" action="test.php" onsubmit="return saveScrollPositions(this);">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="scrollx" id="scrollx" value="0" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="scrolly" id="scrolly" value="0" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="reciept_id" value="' . $_POST['reciept_id'] . '">';
    echo '<textarea name="internal_notes">';
        if ($_POST['internal_notes'] == '') { 
        echo 'No internal notes.'; 
        } else {
        echo $_POST['internal_notes'];
        }
    echo '</textarea>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">';
    echo '</form>';     

$scrollx = 0;
$scrolly = 0;

if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrollx'])) {
$scrollx = $_REQUEST['scrollx'];
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['scrolly'])) {
$scrolly = $_REQUEST['scrolly'];
}
?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.scrollTo(<?php echo "$scrollx" ?>, <?php echo "$scrolly" ?>);
</script>
```

This works fine. When i press Save, it posts and the page returns to the scroll position.
However i want to remove the submit-button, and insetad use onblur="submit();" on the "internal_notes" field.

However... This does not work. How do I combine the submit and the "saveScrollPositions()" function?

Comment: dude when this is a javascript question then why have you written the code with php which is making it unreadable

Comment: and also i can't copy paste it to check the problem

Comment: My questions does not involve the javascript source itself ... Where do you see any javascript in the code above? (other than onsubmit and onblur). However, I can post my javascript, if you think it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your js functions are ok, I really would like to see submit(), try this:

1) add to your form an ID, i.e: `id='notes'`

2) change de onblur by this code:

```
onblur="saveScrollPositions(document.getElementById('notes')); submit();"
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BWgeG/2/) you can see a functional example

Comment: I have already tried that... I'll throw a post including the function.